# Full Screen Video Background with content below the fold

Tags: html, css, video, background

Working on implementing a full screen video background with content under the fold.

So far I have been able to get the full screen video working without issue. The problem is I have been unable to figure out how to add content under the video. Aka the video should stop under the fold:

GOAL: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/0fa4atfpec

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div id='videoBG' class="row">

<video autoplay loop muted poster="screenshot.jpg" id="background">
<source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<p id='mainHeader'> Header Title </p>


</div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class='row'> 

<h1> Start of the second section below the video</h1>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the viewport size
This quick test worked for me

```
<div style="background-color:red;width:100vw;height:100vh">
</div>
<div>
    hi
 <ul>
  <li>ho</li>
  <li>ho</li>
  <li>ho</li>
  <li>ho</li>
  <li>ho</li>
  <li>ho</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could give it a margin-top of 100vh, so 100% of the height of the viewport.

```
h1 { margin-top: 100vh; }
```

As I used here: https://jsfiddle.net/t2f1Lau6/1/

Answer (score 1):

Make video container `div#videoBG` occupy `100vh`. This way, you can impact inside elements such as `#mainHeader` without pushing the section below. Also, I added `box-sizing: border-box` & reseted `margin`s & `padding`s to avoid unwanted gaps between `section`s.

Embed snippet breaks viewport height so check it externally:

[External JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/eujyz3r3/2/)